# Corner Refine Method, CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX, from AcUro with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

**Hi There**

I want to increase the accuracy of the marker detection from aruco.detectMarkers. So, I want to use [Corner Refine Method with CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#gafce26321f39d331bc12032a72b90eda6), but I do not understand how it is implemented in python.

Sample code:

```
frame = cv.imread("test.png") 
gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
para = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
det_corners, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(gray,dictionary,parameters=para)
aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame,det_corners,ids)
```

Things I have tried:

```
para.cornerRefinementMethod()
para.cornerRefinementMethod(aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX)
para.cornerRefinementMethod.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX
para = aruco.DetectorParameters_create(aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX)
para = aruco.DetectorParameters_create(para.cornerRefinementMethod(aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX))
```

They did not work, I’m pretty new to python ArUco so I hope that there is a simple and obvious solution.

I would also Like to implement enclosed markers like in the [Documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QU9KoBtjSM2kF6ITOjQ76xqL7H0TEtXriJX5kwi9Kgc/edit#heading=h.h86u77ckbjh3)(Page 4). Do you happen to know if there is a way to generate these enclosed markers in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first part of your question, you were pretty close: I assume your trouble is in switching and tweaking the "para" options. If so, you only need to set the corresponding values in the parameters object like

```
para.cornerRefinementMethod = aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX
```

Note that "aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX"  is simply an integer. You can verify this by typing `type(aruco.CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX)` in the console. Thus assigning values to the "para" object works like mentioned above.

You might also want to tweak the `para.cornerRefinementWinSize` which seems to be implemented in units of code pixels, not actual image pixel units.

Concerning the second part, you might have to write a function, that adds the boxes at the corner points, which you can get using the `detectMarker` function. Note that the corner points are always ordered clockwise, thus you can easily assign the correct offset values (like "up & left", "up & right" etc.).

Answer (score 0):

para.cornerRefinementMethod = 1
may work.